# Unable to unlock Boot-loader

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bootloader

My android device is 4.4.2 with MT6592.

I am not able to unlock its boot-loader.

After commands ….

**adb reboot bootloader**

**fastboot oem unlock**

Android device asks permission. I confirmed on android device by pressing Volume Up key.
There is no change on device screen and computer screen even after 30 min.

I checked its connectivity by a command.

**adb devices**

**List of devices attached**

**x.x.x.x device**

Apart from this I changed USB cable and USB port. However, there is no change.

If I go for commands …

**adb reboot bootloader**

**fastboot flash recovery twrp.img**

No TWRP images is compatible.

Please guide me to fix it.

Regards

GNS

Comment: Are you sure this tablet is unlockable _this way_? Not every device (in fact, few) supports the fastboot command. And also, are you using a TWRP built for your device? If not and if you can't find one, then no you can't just flash anything else and call it a day.

Comment: @AndyYan What should happen on bootloader unlock? A factory reset, which disables adb (and sometimes pauses fastboot) Reboot, turn adb back on, try again

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried many times to unblock its boot-loader, every time its stuck same way. I am able to root it but not able to unlock its boot-loader. How do I know, this device’s boot-loader can be unlocked or not? If it’s un-lockable, is it not possible to unlock its boot-loader? Please elaborate and guide me to unlock it boot-loader.